# Adding and removing class from buttons in ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, function, click

I have the following jQuery/ajax script:

```
jQuery("input.button").click(function(){
   jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('before');
        jQuery(this).addClass('after');
        jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
});
```

Which handles clicking on buttons such as these:

```
<div id="32"><input type="button" class="button before"/></div>
<div id="33"><input type="button" class="button before"/></div>
```

The adding and removing of classes to whichever but is clicked does not work however.  It works for a single button with an ID, i.e.:

```
jQuery("input#button1").click(function(){
```

But not when I use classes.  What changes do I need to make to get this script to add or remove classes to whichever button is clicked when I just use a class for the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cache the selector, try the following:

```
jQuery("input.button").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id': $this.closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        $this.removeClass('before');
        $this.addClass('after');
        $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
});
```